# Pivot table on imported data showing all zeroed

Tags: vba, excel

'//I have imported a .csv file and then I applied pivot table to the imported 'data but the issue is I am getting all zeroes in pivot table . (all using 'vba)).Want help//

```
       Sub RRCJABO()

        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete


        'Importing data to sheet2


        Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2"
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & GetFile, Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "logexportdata"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With


        'Inserting a blank Column at Column B

        Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate


        'Extracting Date from DateTime

        Cells(2, 2).Value = "=INT(A2)"
        Dim LastRowA As Long
        Dim LastRowB As Long
        LastRowA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & LastRowA),`Type:=xlFillDefault                            `
        Range("A2:A" & LastRowA).Value = Range("B2:B" & LastRowB)
        Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete


        'Insert pivot table (calling pivot table procedure inside mai procedure) 

        pivotpmpdcp


       End Sub

Function GetFile() As String
    Dim filename__path As Variant
    filename__path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Csv (*.CSV), *.CSV", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If filename__path = False Then Exit Function
    GetFile = filename__path
End Function

Sub pivotpmpdcp()

    'Declare Variables

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As pivottable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long


    'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("pmpdcp").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "pmpdcp"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("pmpdcp")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


    'Define Data Range

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)



    'Define Pivot Cache

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(4, 4), _
    TableName:="pivotpmpdcp")


    'Insert Blank Pivot Table

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(3, 3), TableName:="pivotpmpdcp")


    'Insert Row Fields

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivotpmpdcp").PivotFields("Object")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
    End With


    'Insert Column Fields

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivotpmpdcp").PivotFields("Time")
     .Orientation = xlColumnField
     .Position = 1
    End With


    'Insert Data Field1

    With `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivotpmpdcp").PivotFields("EUtranCellFDD.pmPdcpBitrateDlDrbMax")`
     .Orientation = xlDataField
     .Position = 1
     .Function = xlMax
     .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
     .Name = "EUtranCellFDD.pmPdcpBitrateDlDrbMax"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines:

*They attempt to create a `PivotTable` and not a `PivotCache`, as such the `PivotCache` later used to create the `PivotTable` is `Nothing`*

```
'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(4, 4), _
    TableName:="pivotpmpdcp")
```

With these:

```
'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches _
    .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
```

This error was not prompted due to the inefficient use of:

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
```

At the beginning of the first procedure. `ON Error Resume Next` disables the prompt for errors.

The `On Error Resume` was used to bypass the error prompt in case the `Sheet2` was not present when the code attempted to delete it, however it should had been restated immediately, after obtaining the desired effect, using `On Error Goto 0` as follows.

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:
[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much ....This is my first question in stackflow....I will check the code with ur suggested changes and i ll revert to u......Once again thank you so much....

Comment: Sorry there was no effect of those changes......but to my understanding there is somthing associated with importing....how i came to this conclusion is that if I appiled the same pivot table code for copied data(copied means ctrl+c not by vba) the pivot table works fine.....and furthur if i copy that imported data to another worksheet and if i apply pivot table to it the result is all zeroes....... So i feel that there is some mistake with importing data itself.............

Answer (score 0):

Also check this line in the `.QueryTables.Add` procedure:

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
```

Everything, except first column, is imported as as text or skipped.

Use this table for reference and have a look at this [QueryTable.TextFileColumnDataTypes Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193261(v=office.15).aspx):

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for sharing this table @EEM.....it helped me a lot. I tried with different values and hurrah!!!! it worked......and this is the edit i ve made.................TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 2)

Comment: Glad to know that the code is working now, it helps a lot the latest info you shared. Appreciate if you accept this answer and help us to keep the side updated...